# HubConnection.getConnectionId() returns null in signalR in android

Tags: java, android, signalr

I am using signalR java client, i am using this method for connecting the host 
but getting negotiation exception and connectionid returs null

```
connection = new HubConnection(host);
        hub = connection.createHubProxy("Chat");
                hub.subscribe(MainActivity.this);

        hub.on("addChatMessage", new SubscriptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("test", "entered in hub.on method");
            }
        });



        // connection.start();
        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start();
        try {
            awaitConnection.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("<<<Exception>>>",  ""+ e.toString() + "<<<>>>"
                    + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e("<<<Exception>>>", "" + e.toString() + "<<<>>>"
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.e("", "connectionId : "+ connection.getConnectionId());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hub = connection.createHubProxy("wallpostChat");
hub.subscribe(MainActivity.this);

hub.on("addChatMessage", new SubscriptionHandler() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("test", "entered in hub.on method");
    }
});
```

Comment: hi daniel and asd, thanks for your response, but you have given me the same code which i am using, can you please explain or can you please give me any code

Comment: I have successfully integrated SignalR java client after some googling